# Accumulation point of a topological space only if there exists a sequence converging to it

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I am working on this problem:

Let $(V, d)$ be a metric space and $A \subseteq V$. Prove that $a \in V$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $A$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=a$.

What I am struggling with is to "construct" this sequence and formulate the proof in a nice way.

So given $a$ is a limit point of $A$, I know that for any given $\varepsilon > 0$, $B(a;\varepsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. So for any positive integer $r > 0$, I can find an $x_r$ for which $d(x_r,a)<1/r$. Now this is where I get stuck writing the proof. I know that I should be able to associate a sequence with this converging to $a$, but I cannot get it on the paper.

For the other way around I would say, since we know there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $a$, for any given $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n > M$ implies $d(x_n,a)<\varepsilon$. I don't know how to finish this part of the proof.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean "accumulation point"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My definition of **limit point**: A point $a$ is a limit point of $A$ if $B(a,\varepsilon)\cap A$ always contains an element $\neq a$, for every $\varepsilon>0$. In this case, the proposition is false, since every element $a\in A$ is the limit of the constant sequence $(x_n=a)_n\subseteq A$.

If in the definition we don't require that $B(a,\varepsilon)\cap A$ contains an element *different* from $a$, then the proposition is correct.

Assuming we are in this last case, then your proof is basically completed: In the first part, for every $\varepsilon>0$ you can choose $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $N^{-1}<\varepsilon$, so for all $m\geqslant N$ $$d(a,x_m)<\frac{1}{m}\leqslant\frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon$$ which means $x_n\rightarrow a$.

The second part is also correct: Suppose $x_n\rightarrow a$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $x_n\in B(a,\varepsilon)\cap A$, for all $n>N$, in particular $B(a,\varepsilon)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ and $a$ is a limit point of $A$.